# MySQL Update Column, One to Many

Tags: mysql, sql-update, left-join

I have the following tables:

```
t1, 418932 rows
t2, 461904 rows
```

with these columns:

```
t1 columns: ID NUMBER TITLE
t2 columns: ID NUMBER NAME
```

t1 example

```
1 123 The Iliad
2 124 The Inferno
3 125 Freakonomics
```

t2 example

```
1 123 Homer
2 124 Dante
3 125 Levitt
3 125 Dubner
```

As is shown here, t2 can have several different NAME entries for a NUMBER in t1. I want to copy t1.ID to t2.ID, joined by NUMBER. I have tried several different variations, including:

```
UPDATE t2
LEFT JOIN t1 ON t2.NUMBER = t1.NUMBER
SET t2.ID = t1.ID
```

and

```
UPDATE t1, t2 
SET t2.ID = t1.ID 
WHERE t2.NUMBER = t1.NUMBER
```

But both are really slow, for example, after one hour, only ~800 rows were copied. My server has 32GB ram, so memory is not a problem.

Can anyone suggest a better, faster or more efficient way to write this query? Or is this sort of speed normal?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Solved. As the comment from Zafar suggested, I forgot to add an index in both tables.

Comment: id and number columns are indexed in both tables, and integer or else....

Comment: why not create a new table t3 without index and then do a INSERT SELECT , drop t2 and rename t3

Comment: Many thanks Zafar. I completely forgot to add an index. Query execution time now 52 seconds.